# How to stream audio via bluetooth to an airplay speaker?

Tags: audio, bluetooth

I am trying to send audio using bluetooth to my raspberry pi which then should forward the music to an airplay speaker (in my case a HomePod). The first step of sending music to the pi is straightforward. However, I am really struggling with the second step. I am new to this and overwhelmed by (I think) solutions like [forked-daapd](https://github.com/ejurgensen/forked-daapd) . Another solution I found is [BabelPod](http://faden.me/2018/03/18/babelpod.html) . What do you think would be an easy solution for my problem? If someone could share its experiences or give me a hint, I'd highly appreciate that.